# Adjoining $i$ to $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ring-isomorphism

Let $I$ be an ideal of a ring. I know that $I$ is maximal if and only if $R/I$ is a field.

There's an example I'm working with, $(x^2+1) \subset \mathbb{C}[x]$ which is clearly not maximal because $(x^2+1) \subset (x+i)$.

However, if we consider $\mathbb{C}[x]/(x^2+1) \cong \mathbb{C}[i] = \mathbb{C}$ and $\mathbb{C}$ is a field, which should mean that $(x^2+1)$ is indeed maximal. It's clear that $\mathbb{C}[x]/(x^2+1) \not \cong \mathbb{C}$, but then what is that ring?

I suppose my question is, what ring is $\mathbb{C}[x]/(x^2+1)$?

Comment: It's $\mathbb C^2$

Comment: You should always consider trying $p(x) \mapsto (p(a),p(b))$ for appropriate values of $a$ and $b$. And the obvious values to try here are $i$ and $-i$.

Comment: If $p(x)$ is an irreducible polynomial over a field $F$, then $F[x]/(p(x)) \cong F[\alpha]$ for a root $\alpha$ of $p$. The problem here is that $x^2+1$ is not irreducible over $\Bbb C$.

Comment: The equality C[i] = C that you wrote makes no sense, because that i there is not the one inside C. You are denoting by i two different things. That never works.

Comment: It'll make you go cross $i$-ed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apply the Chinese remainder theorem to get $\mathbb{C}[x] / (x^2+1) = \mathbb{C}[x] / (x+i) \times \mathbb{C}[x] / (x-i) = \mathbb{C}^2$.